# How to get my speakers and headphones to play audio at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, speakers

My speakers have a port to plug my headphones into. Whenever I plug them in, I only hear sound through my headphones, and not through my speakers anymore. I would want to hear sound through both of them. How could I achieve this? I have a (built-in) IDT soundcard (which was standard in my HP laptop) and run Windows 7. Could anyone please help?

Comment: This is usually configured in the BIOS or the software that comes with the driver for the audio device.

Comment: It's very unlikely to be possible with the port built into speakers. It's done in hardware there.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg There doesn't come any software with the device itself. Would there be a way to configure this myself?

Comment: @studentjwz: Did you check the BIOS?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg No I didn't. I don't have a clue at all how this can be done. I have no experience with adjusting settings in the BIOS. Could you please explain to me how I should go about doing this?

Comment: @studentjwz: What is the model of your laptop? The procedure will be largely dependant upon the BIOS that the device is using. It makes sense to check the manual first to even determine if this option is available in the BIOS.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg The model of my laptop is HP EliteBook 8570w. What option should I be looking for (i.e., how is it usually described)?

Comment: Possible dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/380607/use-internal-speakers-without-unplugging-headphones

Comment: @ernie My hardware and software are different, so I hope that what I want is possible in my case (and I cannot conclude that from the link that you provided). Therefore, I don't think my question is a duplicate.

Comment: Fair enough . . . I'm saying it's a possible dupe as I tend to agree with @gronostaj and the answer in that question, i.e. in most laptops, this is a hardware switch, not a software switch.

Comment: @OliverSalzburg Could you please give me any pointers on what I should alter/look for in the BIOS?

Comment: @studentjwz: When you say your ***speakers*** have a port to plug headphones into, do you mean to say you're using external speakers with your laptop?