# Why both headphones and speakers are active on my windows 8.1?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, speakers

When I plug in my headphones into my laptop, speakers remain active. I have mute speakers mixer so they don't play sounds when headphones are plugged in, but the problem is, some of applications only appear in the speakers mixer and I can't hear them over headphones. I didn't have this problem before.

I already had set headphones as default device on playback devices settings, but that was no help.

Currently I just disable speakers to get all applications sound over headphones but doing this over and over is annoying.

Comment: I think your headphone jack is not properly getting holded in your laptop plug.

Comment: @RenjuChandranchingath Well, before upgrade to 8.1 I didn't have the problem.

Comment: Then please edit your query in that way.

Comment: My problem started when I wrongly plugged in the headphones into the microphone jack, then all this problem started. I'm really really MAD and I won't say bad words here but I haven't foen a solution. Before this happened I had it the way I wanted it (speakers until headphones plugged, then sound just in headphones and speakers muted) I'M SO MAD -_____-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you install the drivers for your audio card? It is also possible that your laptop is not picking up the jack when you plug it in and not mutes the speakers.

Try setting the headphones as BOTH default device AND default communication device (there's a difference and both can be selected).

Comment: I can't find setting you mentioned. Where should I look for it?

Comment: Right click on the system tray icon for sound settings (the speaker icon in the bottom right of your desktop). Select "playback devices" then right-click your headphones and select "Set as Default Communication Device".

Comment: I had set it as Default Device, so there was not Default Communication Device. I changed Default Device to speakers and then did what you told me to do. Seems it works.

Comment: Good to see you fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

I found the only way to resolve this issue was to delete the RealTek HD device in device manager then scan for hardware changes and re install.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Windows 8 laptop and I looked up answers myself to fix the situation and none of them worked. The laptop did not want to detect the headphones, although it played through the headphones and the laptop speakers. So, I did my own thing following part of step one on the Microsoft website (Go to control panel).

Try this out! It may work for you too.

1. Go to Control Panel (If you do not know how to find it follow these steps)

   ```
   a.     Click Start and Control Panel.

   b.     Click Hardware and Sound and then Recording.
   ```
2. Scroll down until you see "RealTek HD Audio Manager (Most likely the last thing on the list)
   Select it opening the program.  When it opens up you should see two circles at the very bottom, under the letters (`A` `B` `C` `D`) . If the bottom circle is highlighted (Headphone outlet) then your laptop knows that your headphones are there. Same for the top circle (recording outlet).

   a. Click `A` and let it play through for both of your laptop speakers

   b. Click `B` and let it play through for headphones output

   c. `C` Should be for recording outlet and I am not sure what `D` is for. Keep it highlighted and exit out after testing if the device (letter you highlighted) and your problem should be solved. If there are still problems then do as I did and try looking through things (Only recommended if you are good at problem solving and/or able to grasp the simple settings of a computer device).

You shouldn't have to go back and change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

Have been wrestling with this for hours. When I muted the "line-in mic" the headphones also muted.

So I right clicked the speaker icon (bottom right corner) and clicked "playback devices". Clicked the "recording" tab and disabled the "microphone line-in" device. No more problems with dual playback devices.